# Given position and rotation position, how to i translate coordinates from one frame to another? (using baxter robot, ROS and python)

Tags: python, matrix, transformation, ros

So what i want to do essentially, is transforming a set of coordinates, from one frame to another. I have my camera set on my robot's hand (which i know the position and orientation), and i'm viewing a certain object, and reading coordinates from the cameras frame.

How do i convert those coordinate to my base frame? I know that i can just first reverse the orientation, using the inverse orientation matrix, and then use some kind of translational matrix, but how do i obtain that matrix? Once the orientation is corrected, how do i do the translation?

Answer (score 0):

**Note:** I think this is better suited as a comment but I lack the reputation points.

Assuming both your frames are available in ROS, i.e. if you run (as specified [here](http://wiki.ros.org/tf#tf_echo)):

```
rosrun tf tf_echo /source_frame /target_frame
```

you should see the translation and rotation between both frames. Then you could use `lookupTransform` to obtain this information inside your code (see: [TF tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/tf/Tutorials/Writing%20a%20tf%20listener%20%28Python%29)).

Hope this helps.